# Why hasn't Canada legislated to assist Hong Kong protesters?

Tags: international-relations, canada, hong-kong

The US Congress is trying to enact the [Hong Kong Human Rights and Democracy Act of 2019](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Human_Rights_and_Democracy_Act).

Canada has [many Hongkongers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hong_Kong_Canadians). Why hasn't Canada tried too?

Comment: How ironic. The country always complains that Russia is meddling in their country. But have no problems meddling in other countries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect it has something to do with the level of pressure China can put on Canada, compared to how much Canada can fight back against that coercion.

As a result of the arrest of the Huawei founder's daughter - a much less direct challenge than to support HK protesters - we have had severe trade disruptions, 2 citizens, one of which an ex-diplomat, jailed on trumped up charges and another Canadian, a drug dealer, has had his sentence bumped up to the death penalty.

For our pains in acting on a US extradition request, we had President Trump shortly afterwards Twitter that the whole thing ["could be fixed with a deal"](https://www.scmp.com/news/china/diplomacy/article/2177540/donald-trump-says-would-intervene-arrest-huawei-cfo-sabrina).

I suspect that, at this point, only a coordinated and concerted effort by Western countries to diplomatically punish China for its suppression of HK citizen rights would have much effect.  And this is the kind of situation where recent US unilateralism and unpredictability makes that level of coordination less likely than usual.

So Canada's sitting this one out out of caution/timidity, yes.  But I honestly doubt too many people are sympathetic to the CCP, even among more recent immigrants.

Comment: Britain finds itself in much the same position. Only last night the Chinese put out accusations of British "interference" and warning that if such continue Britain could get "burned". Not sure what that means, but we do have 300,000 UK citizens currently living in Hong Kong - some of whom have been there years and call the place "home".

Comment: @WS2  yes, we are living in interesting times again.  I fear that Xi is so caught up in his rhetoric that he doesn't have the flexibility to adapt.  China should, naturally, raise to ascendency over time.  They have the population, albeit aging, the financial, intellectual and industrial muscle.  They - as someone recently said - are much more of a potential threat than the USSR ever was, but they also come without much of the baggage of the USSR.  The world could "do business with them".  The one risk is uniting the world against them, something HK and the Uighur is a very good stab at doing.

Comment: The Chinese ambassador to the UK, speaking on BBC TV last night was quite forthright in his complaints about British "interference", though he didn't make himself terribly clear as to what form the interference had taken. Notwithstanding his quite angry-looking façade, he did at one point appear to congratulate Britain for the manner in which the police deal with demonstrators. This could be a big moment in Chinese history, coinciding with "big moments" in Britain (Brexit), USA (impeachment?) etc. How many big moments can the wold handle simultaneously.